# Phonegap (1.7.0) + node.js + socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to build an **Android (v.4.0.3)** app with **Phonegap (Cordova 1.7.0)**, **Node.js (v0.6.18)** and **Socket.io (v0.9)** on the other side. I need to do this for my school project, but I hit a wall due to my limited knowledge. I even thought that socket.io can’t be used within Phonegap (Android). Would it be possible to get some directions, link or other kind of help so that I would be able to establish connection. Connection is the main problem. The documentation is not helping me enough.

I would really appreciate some tips on how to establish a connection. I installed node inspector, but nothing. *Server.js* is running on an *Amazon EC2* micro instance on *port 8080*. 
I read somewhere that Android doesn't support websockets.

But isn't it true that Phonegap actually grabs the whole HTML page and packages it up to run as a native application within a UIWebView or WebView?

So in that case it is the webkit. And this one supports websockets if I am not mistaken.

Regards,

Tomaz

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap) for websockets.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked almost 3 years ago though. If you need to use node.js and cordova/phonegap together on Android or iOS see [jxcore-cordova](http://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova)